# Computer goes to blue screen everytime i try to transfer a file over wifi?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ftp, android, file-transfer

My pc goes to this screen as seen below.
[image]

I am trying to transfer songs folder from my pc which is of 10.5 GB size to my 
SD card in my mobile with android 4.4.2 installed.
I am using the *android* app **`my ftp server`** on my mobile as ftp server.

And i am using **`OSToto Hostspot`** on *windows* to turn my PC internal wireless as a wifi hotspot.

Then i am using filezilla to transfer files between the PC and the mobile.
But the problem is while file is transferring my PC comes to a blue screen randomly after some random amount of files are transferred some times it come to a blue screen after 1 GB files are transferred, some times  i get the screen after 2 Gb and so on.

The blue screen makes the PC restart automatically
This is my wireless device :

```
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
Connection Speed:   300 Mbps
```

EDIT : here is what i get when i run bluescreenview on the dmp file that i get.
I dont know any other way to open the dmp file.

```
022216-13806-01.dmp 2/22/2016 7:48:33 PM    SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED 0x1000007e  ffffffff`c0000005   fffff880`04c069bf   fffff880`0bacc178   fffff880`0bacb9d0   HDAudBus.sys    HDAudBus.sys+61763b0                    x64 nwifi.sys+69bf                  C:\Windows\Minidump\022216-13806-01.dmp 2   15  7600    320,594 2/22/2016 7:49:10 PM
```

Comment: Do you have a wifi router? You can use , for example esFileExplorer on your android device and then use normal (smb) file sharing

Comment: Yes I have router, I am leaving now for some work.I will try that probably tommrow, i will let you know the results

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: have you uploaded the dmp file?

Comment: i dont know why the dmp file i saw was old dated  about a year old, so i didn't upload.And there are only one file.I guess i have to try to delete the file and make the problem reoccur.Thanks

Comment: 022216-13806-01.dmp 2/22/2016 7:48:33 PM SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED 0x1000007e ffffffff`c0000005 fffff880`04c069bf fffff880`0bacc178 fffff880`0bacb9d0 HDAudBus.sys HDAudBus.sys+61763b0     x64 nwifi.sys+69bf     C:\Windows\Minidump\022216-13806-01.dmp 2 15 7600 320,594 2/22/2016 7:49:10 PM

Comment: Do you get the same crashes if you transfer a file while in Safe Mode?  You are going to need to run `windbg` in order to get the real cause of the crash.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn off the OSToto Hostspot application and try to send files over the WiFi to another machine will it still give you the blue screen?

If not I'd say that you've found the culprit.

If it still crashes, check your RAM and if you have Microsoft Security Essentials installed, uninstall it. It's known to be able to produce a 1E blue screen in some cases.

Comment: well i dont have another machine i have only mobile to test that, also i don't know how would i transfer files over wifi to my mobile other than this, but i will google it.